# how can two component refer to each other

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have two components in angular 2. ContainerOne and ContainerTwo

ContainerOne refer to ContainerTwo, and ContinerTwo refer to ContainerOne in our directives:[]

The error is:

> Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the
>   View of component 'ContainerTwo'

Class one:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {ContainerTwo} from './container-two';

@Component({
  selector: 'container-one'
, template: '
<div *ngIf="level > 0" 
    style="width: {{level * 20}}px; 
    height: {{level * 20}}px; 
    background-color: red;">

  <container-two [level]="level - 1"></container-two>

</div>'
, directives: [ContainerTwo]
})
export class ContainerOne {

    @Input() level: number;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Class two:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {ContainerOne} from './container-one';

@Component({
  selector: 'container-two'
, template: '
<div *ngIf="level > 0" 
  style="width: {{level * 20}}px; 
  height: {{level * 20}}px; 
  background-color: blue;">

    <container-one [level]="level - 1"></container-one>

</div>'
, directives: [ContainerOne]
})
export class ContainerTwo {

    @Input() level: number;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

app.ts:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {ContainerOne} from './container-one';
import {ContainerTwo} from './container-two';

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
, template: '<container-one [level]="10"></container-one>'
, directives: [ContainerOne, ContainerTwo]
})
export class App {

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

*(its a skeleton of my problem, the real containers are more complicated, and not similar )*
*this sample program want to draw some div in each other while level > 0*

What is the problem? Maybe a reference circle? Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, reference cycle. Each `*.ts` file is a module (most of time), but modules are loaded one by one and cyclic dependencies are not handled automatically. You should use `forwardRef` to break this cycle, check this [link](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: it was an interesting article, tnx. I put into my code this: directives: [@Inject(forwardRef(() => ContainerOne], but not working

Comment: there isn't error. It does not recognize the directive, so it can't generate error.

Comment: remove Comp2 from app directives, and add  forwardrefs to both Comp1 and Comp2 directives.

Comment: It's not working, and I don't understand you. The  directives must contain Comp1, and Comp2 to template processing...If I remove ContainerOne from ContainerTwo's providers, the program is runing but only to first level, The chain will be stoped at Comp2